# Can I edit ASP.net website in Dreamweaver

Tags: asp.net, dreamweaver

Is it possible to user Dreamweaver to edit (design not code) an ASP.net website instead of Microsoft Expression web? Does Dreamweaver support master pages or ASP.net controls?

Comment: witch version of dreamweaver you have ?

Answer (score -1):

Everything is ok with Dreamweaver, you can easily edit websites on it (note that you have to republish the final website again).

It is a IDE like Visual Studio or Expression etc. Nothing weird about it.

Comment: I couldnt find much resources on web relating asp.net and dreamweaver

Comment: Are you kidding me? you can easily create asp.net pages with it. you even can code with `Notepad` Dreamweaver is just an IDE and helps you code faster. I myself recommand you to use VisualStudio IDE for Asp.net, it's the best editor for Asp.net pages

Comment: He is looking for some tutorials and resources to quick start developing asp.net pages using dreamweaver.

Comment: @Farzin, He wasn't looking for some tutorial or tools, He didn't know that Deramweaver is able toedit asp.net pages or not. Read question again

Comment: @Nasser, And you read it again and consider -Is there any resources?- sentence !

Comment: @Farzin, It's not the main section of the question, it isobviouse that he wasn't aware that Dreamweaver is able to edit or no? By the way I reckon that by `Is there any resources` he means that can you give a link that shows dreamweaver is able to edit or not? but you gave him the tools.

Comment: @Nasser, Let him know himself what was he looking for.

Comment: @REZA, could you write in English please? Now many people don't understand you.